# What would be a good tracing library for a C multithreaded program?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, trace

I'm writing a multithreaded server using Ptrheads and I want to trace the execution of individual threads.

What would be a good tracing library for this?

Comment: One problem with relying on tracing to resolve multithreaded bugs is that the act of tracing itself can hide the bug, so when you remove traces it suddenly reappears!

Comment: @James mmm didn't quite understand how that can happen. What would be the reason for bugs getting hidden while tracing is on?

Comment: @Dulanja: Tracing tools sometimes force waits and syncs that affect the thread's timing behavior.

Comment: Hmm. What would be a better way to find out the bugs? Definitely debugging is not an option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[cTrace](http://ctrace.sourceforge.net/)** is an good option.

Answer (score 1):

[NPTL](http://nptltracetool.sourceforge.net/) sounds exactly like what you need. I have tried unsuccessfully to install it, though, and it seems dated a bit but the features are great. If you succeed in installing it, drop me a line through here! There is also [PAPI](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/), but it's tough to handle, and there's finally Valgrind (particularly Cachegrind) for certain subset of debugging needs. Hope this helps.

Comment: As I understood NPTL trace tool is to trace inside the threading library itself. I actually want to trace the user program. I may have asked the question incorrectly :) Nonetheless, those low levels tool you mentioned will be helpful for me when digging deep. Thanks.